# Can not retrieve data json from the server using ajax on cordova

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I tried to call / search data by ID , from the server using ajax in cordova , but when I click to display the data " undefined" , what's wrong ???

This my html

```
<input type="text" id="result"  value=""/>
<a href="javascript:get()" style="text-decoration: none"><button>get</button></a>
<div id="result2"></div>

            function get (){    
                var qrcode = document.getElementById ("result").value;
                var dataString="qrcode="+qrcode;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://localhost/book/find.php",
                    crossDomain: true,
                    cache: false,
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function(result){
                    var result=$.parseJSON(result);
                    $.each(result, function(i, element){        
                        var id_code=element.id_code;
                        var qrcode=element.qrcode;
                        var judul=element.judul;
                        var hasil2 = 
                            "QR Code: " + qrcode + "<br>" +                 
                            "Judul: " + Judul;  

                        document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = hasil2;  
                    }); 
                    }
                });
            }
```

This my script on server

```
include "db.php";

    $qrcode= $_GET['qrcode'];
    $array = array();

    $result=mysql_query("select * from book WHERE qrcode LIKE '%{$qrcode}%'");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  //fetch the result from query into an array
    {
        $array[] =$row['qrcode'];
        $array[] =$row['judul'];
        $array[] =$row['jilid'];

    }
    echo json_encode($array);  
    }
```

Comment: `element.id_code`. It would seem that the php script does not define this object, right?

Comment: Thank @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy, yes i do not put element.id_code on the server because I do not want to display it. whether influential ?

Comment: So this is defined in `db.php`?

Comment: yes, `db.php` used only to call the Only Database

Comment: Change `var dataString="qrcode="+qrcode;` to `var dataString="qrcode="+encodeURIComponent(qrcode);`

Comment: I try but still value "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

try to change your parameter in calling ajax

`var dataString = {qrcode : qrcode }`;

Comment: thanks @Jeric Cruz, it's some value not want to appear , blank

Comment: try to remove some space in declaring qrcode, var qrcode = document.getElementById("result").value;

Comment: i try but no change , I think the fault is in `var datastring` , and the server can not read `$qrcode = $_GET[ 'qrcode']`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your php code as below

```
 include "db.php";

$qrcode= $_GET['qrcode'];
$array = array();

$result=mysql_query("select * from book WHERE qrcode LIKE '%{$qrcode}%'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  //fetch the result from query into an array
{
    $array[] =['qrcode'=>$row['qrcode'],'judul'=>$row['judul'],'id_code'=>$row['jilid']];
}
echo json_encode($array);  
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Vinie, but value not want to appear , blank.

Comment: which value not appering?

Answer (score 0):

> RESOLVED the problem is. I try to replace with this script and the result was the same as I expected.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
    $array[]=$row++;
}
echo json_encode($array);
```